# How to add extra_context to django admin panel

Tags: django, admin

As I know I can see context of page adding {% debug %} to template.

I tried to add extra context using django_with_extra_context_admin library:

```
def get_extra_context(self, request, **kwargs):
    extra_context = super().get_extra_context(request, **kwargs) or {}
    extra_context.update({
        'testextra': 1,
    })
    return extra_context
```

And I don't see this context neither {% debug %} nor {{ extra_context }} nor {{ testextra }}.

Next I tried to add context by redefining changelist_view of ModelAdmin:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context = {'test': 1}
    return super(RegisterDaposAdmin, self).changelist_view(
        request, extra_context=extra_context,
    )
```

And I don't see this context neither {% debug %} nor {{ extra_context }} nor {{ test }}.

Finally, I tried to add context in urls:

```
path("admin/", admin.site.urls, {'extra_context': {'mycontext': 1}}),
```

And I don't see this context neither {% debug %} nor {{ extra_context }} nor {{ mycontext }}.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in your apps admin.py file add

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import model_name


admin.site.register(model_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Problem is solved. I expected context in change_list_results, but got it in change_list. It is not good, but I can have empty change_list_results and add everything in change_list. That's my solution.

Comment: Could you please confirm this as the answer?

Comment: Hm, this thread is about integration third-party library in django admin panel that is not for django admin panel. You need to dive deep into source code of django admin panel with inheritance of views from models. It has no obvious solution like you suggest.